# Deploy service on existing VM

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-clouddrive

I want to handle some maintenance in existing VM, which is already hosting a website. So I created a web role and package it into .cspkg file. I didn't get any way to deploy this on existing VM. Lets say I don't have any no of remaining new instance of Vm I can create, and also I don't want to delete previously created one. I just want to add this in existing VM. 
 I actually want to mount a drive from blob storage. So I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81413/Windows-Azure-Drives-Part-1-Configure-and-Mounting) link to create web role for it.
Isn't it possible to do the same by creating a small .exe file with same logic to mount drive in c#. Which I can execute any time in VM and do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you have a web role deployed that you would like to update with a new package.
This is possible, amongst other ways, through the admin portal.
Select the cloud service you'd like to update and then your deployment slot (production or staging) and you would be able to click the update button on the bottom toolbar which would open a pop-up allowing you to provide a new package and config files.

[image: Update dialog]

A better option would be to deploy the new version to the staging slot, test it and then use VIP Swap to swap between staging and production making the latest package the 'live' one.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But isn't this approach replace the old VM. i.e. if I follow this approach the website hosted on VM and other data, setting along with it get replaced with this new service. I don't want that I want to append that new service to existing VM. That's why I am asking about any alternate way (create an exe) to do it.

Comment: Ok - apologies for misunderstanding your question. what do you mean by append that new service? is that a second web role? if that is so I do not believe this is possible without either re-deploying

Comment: Thats OK now I get a straight "NOT Possible". But I have to achieve that functionality some how. Is it possible to create a application which can can mount(or unmount) azure drive in a way I want? If yes I will need some help.

Comment: I believe that initialisation of CloudDrive from a standalone app will not work, but you can enhance your web role to include that capability? have a page or even a rest endpoint that will mount or unmound the drive as needed? I have not tried this, but it should work.